# Exaustive lists of all possible errors for various Windows API calls?

Tags: winapi, getlasterror

[`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for example. When I get `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, what are all the possible values that can be returned by [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? MSDN doesn't say. It mentions some and I can guess others, but how (if at all) can I be sure that my `switch` statement will never reach `default`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a list doesn't exist and in fact you can't ever have such a list. In some future version of Windows a function may well start returning an error code that did not exist when you compiled your program.

The standard way to deal with this is handle any error codes that you know about that need special treatment, and let all others fall through to a default handler.  Call [`FormatMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get a descriptive text string for the error.

Comment: yeah sure, and suddenly all applications that did checks on INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE stops working, suuuuure ;)

Comment: @Bartosz When Vista came out, there were lots of functions that started returning error codes that they had not returned in earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: @Bartosz: As an example, it is not uncommon to get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED these days on functions which used to be entirely "harmless".